# New to SUMo (Simulation of Urban MObility ) , need help to understand and solve it

Tags: simulator, sumo, traffic-simulation

i need to understand and find a possible solution to this problem.i am fairly new to this simulator but cannot find anything about the above mentioned problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY23O.png

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: **[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. If you want people to help you, you need to provide more information, like what you have tried before posting the question. You could also include the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To let the traci_pedestrian_crossing scenario run, you need to start the python script runner.py (you might need to install python to do so). It should generate the network which is mentioned as missing.